# How would I use a variable in printf to align text?

Tags: java

Say I wanted to align some text left, and a certain pre calculated amount. What is the correct syntax?

```java
int left = 10+months[i].length();
System.out.printf("%s%14.1s%14.1s\n",months[i], temps[i], prec[i]);
```

Comment: It's not clear what you want. You can use any string for your format string, so you can build it if the 'left' value should be in there.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use minus sign inside your first argument. You can also build your first argument as a regular String. For example, following code will print the String with three elements left aligned with width equal to your precalculated "left" value:

```
System.out.printf("%-" + left + "s%-" + left + "s%-"  + left + "s\n", months[i], temps[i], prec[i]);
```